# Store a FFT with a minimal amount of data

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, fourier-transform

I have an array `x` of length 1024 (stored as 16 bits integers, named for example `np.int16` in numpy/python), i.e. **the size of x is 1024*2 = 2048 bytes.**

(*Remark : x comes from an audio .wav file, stored as 16 bits integers, as it is very common. But it is also very common to interpret it as a float array, with values in $[-1, +1]$ by doing:* `x = x * 1.0 / 2^16`)

When I take `fft(x)`, as the input was real, there is some symmetry that makes that I only need to store half of the array `fft(x)`, that's often also called `rfft(x)` : **real fft**.

- This means that, by taking `fft`, I translated 1024 real numbers into 512 complex numbers (i.e. can be viewed as 1024 real numbers again) : in a mathematical point of view, we have the same amount of data :

  `1024 real coefficients -- rfft --> 1024 real coefficients`

**But in a programmaing point of view, is it possible to store, losslessly* and without compression, the `fft` of an array of 1024 elements of type `int16` (using 2048 bytes) with 2048 bytes maximum ?**

**If not, what is the minimum number of bytes required to store the `fft` of such an array?**

*remark (*) : by losslessly I mean that the original `x` can be recovered later*

Comment: Your question is unclear. The answer to your first question "Is it possible ...?" is 'yes' (if you don't mind losing accuracy) and 'no' if you mean without losing any detail. Your second question can't be answered either. What do you mean by "minimum number of bytes"? You need some fidelity criterion in order to answer this question.

Comment: Probably you want to look at "fixed-point FFT algorithms"?

Comment: @MattL : I slightly rewrote the question in order to show that I want to keep just enough data about `fft(x)` so that `x` can be recovered later losslessly.

Comment: @Basj: There will always be some level of quantization for the general case, no matter what manner of finite-precision arithmetic that you use. Therefore, you'll never have a generic lossless FFT/IFFT implementation. The key is always the amount of quantization that you can live with, which is application-dependent.

Comment: @JasonR : the question is indeed, *what level* of quantization is needed to be able to restore the original integer array losslessly ?

Comment: You would need to go into reversible/integer transforms etc, which is probably not what you want. Is the purpose to compute the FFT without obtaining the symmetric half of the result? (What people are discussing here is quantization noise and errors, i.e., if you multiply two 16-bit numbers you get a 32-bit number and you will need to quantize to get a 16-bit number back.)

Comment: I also think that you would need to explain why you need/want to compute the FFT for the answer to make sense (if you now would go into reversible/integer transforms and obtain valid answers).

Comment: @Oscar what do you think about this code : www.jjj.de/crs4/integer_fft.c , do you think it could help to design a fixedpoint FFT that is revertible, losslessly ?

Answer (score 5):

In general, quantizing an FFT result is a lossy process.  Given that the FFT twiddle factors are transcendental functions, any finite storage size will result in adding some quantization noise; and that noise increases as the resulting format decreases in bit size.  For extremely sparse FFT results, it may be possible to compress those results, but those are statistically very rare cases.

Comment: At some size the quantization of the FFT result will introduce less noise than required to get within half an LSB of the input data after the round trip.  Thus the properly rounded IFFT will match the quantized input.  Usually this size is larger than the input by around on the order of log(N) additional bits per data type.  Not smaller.

Comment: Note though that coefficient quantization does not add noise. Noise is by definition random and coefficient quantization errors are static. Hence, what you get as a result is a slightly different transform compared to what you expected, but always the same. Then, data quantization will add noise, but these two error sources are inherently different.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I can provide you an (almost) answer:

If you are using a lifting based realization of the complex twiddle factor multiplication with quantized coefficients, the word length will increase with three times the coefficient word length after performing the multiplication. Hence, a direct evaluation would give the initial data word length plus three times the coefficient word length plus 10 (which is the two-logarithm of 1024). This what is needed to store the exact result of the DFT computation using a direct computation. If you instead are using an FFT algorithm, you would be looking at at most nine twiddle factor stages, each adding three times the coefficient word length number of bits.

I guess neither of these numbers are actually what you are looking for, since you probably do not want to write your own DFT/FFT. Also, with these numbers, the question "What do you need the DFT for?" and "How good approximation of the DFT do you need?" arise pretty rapidly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but reading " lifting based realization of the complex twiddle factor multiplication with quantized coefficients" is like reading Egyptian hieroglyphs for me ! Can you precise with a few examples ?

Answer (score -2):

This is not exactly an answer (I hope it will become it soon) but a result based on experience :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write
from scipy.fftpack import rfft, irfft

(fs, x) = read('nowomannocry_16bit_mono.wav')

y = rfft(x)
M = max(abs(y))
y *= 1.0 * (2**23-1) / M               # mapped into [-2^23, 2^23 -1]
y = np.round(y)
y = np.int32(y)   # here we store the fft by using the full width of 24 bits 

z = irfft(y) * M / (2**23-1)
z = np.round(z)
z = np.int16(z)
print z - x, max(abs(z-x))
# [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0] 0
```

According to this small test (done on *Bob Marley's No woman no cry, 16 bit, mono* ;)), **24 bits** seem to be enough to store the FFT of the original signal, in such a way that the original signal can be recovered by RFFT.

I tried with 16, 20, 22 bits, and it wasn't enough.

These are only experiences, but can something be proven in this direction ?

Comment: That is plain "luck" and will, if nothing else, depend on which FFT algortihm is used (and the internal precision). Clearly, if you used double precision floating-point in the computation, it may make sense that 24 bits are enough to store the intermediate result, but it will really be depending on the data stream.

Comment: I agree with Oscar. See hotpaw2's comment on his answer above regarding *bit growth* in FFT implementations.

Comment: I agree with you @Oscar and JasonR, this is plain luck, but there is a number of bits for which we will be **sure** to be able to store losslessly this FFT. What is this number ? This is what I'm trying to find.

Comment: $\infty$... For any number you propose, I am pretty sure that it is possible to find (at least) one input sequence where it doesn't hold. If you want slightly better chances, search for "Integer FFT" and read the first few hits. This will make the coefficient quantization errors reversible if nothing else. Then, rounding the coefficients to a certain number of bits and keeping all bits will actually get you a number (I think they even discuss how you could quantize the intermediate results to some degree). If you are happy with a DFT computation, that would result in fewer bits.

Comment: One reason is the one mentioned in one of the integer FFT papers: you can not find two non-zero numbers in radix-2 representation such that their squares sum up to exactly 1 (which is needed to get the exact reversible transform). It is not formulated as such in the paper, but I can provide a proof if needed.